# Magento 2 When I add a configuration, the product disappears from front end

Tags: product, configurable-product, magento-2.2.5

I am attempting to add configurations for a product, but whenever I add a configuration, it disappears from the front end. When I remove the configuration, the product reappears.

I've also noticed that the Price and Quantity values are grayed out and uneditable, as shown in the image below:

[image: Uneditable Price and Quantity]

Comment: Which configurations you set for a product?

Comment: The Price and Quantity values are grayed out and uneditable >> YES, because this is a configurable product. You can able to edit its child product in the `Configurations` tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure and have it show up on the front end by selecting all of the created Virtual Products and mass editing them via "Update Attributes", and under Advanced Inventory, set the Stock Availability as In Stock and set the quantity to the desired amount.

Also, the grayed out portions are only true for the Configurable product - not the individual virtual products. This allows for setting an individual price for each virtual product. I hope that helps.

Thanks for your willingness to help.